# Sub-folders not being indexed by Search Engines

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, search-engine

Early this year I registered a domain and installed Joomla and Wordpress to try out difference themes and features.
Less than days later the main domain and a sub-folder got indexed by google as following:

- www.example.com (Wordpress installed in the public_html folder)
- www.emample.com/portal (Joomla installation files)

About two weeks ago I cleaned up **everything** and did the following:

- Created a simple HTML5 document (index.html) and placed in the public_html folder
- Created a sob folder called "wiki" (Dokuwiki installation files) www.emample.com/wiki
- Created a sob folder called "blog" (Wordpress installation files) www.emample.com/blog

Since than, only main page index.html has been indexed by google even though its has links to "wiki" and "blog".
Both Wordpress and Dokuwiki have friendly URL (thanks to .httacess)

How could a get my sub-folders indexed by Google? Note: I do not have sub-domains.

**Update 1:**

The website: http://goo.gl/vVvyr9

Comment: Maybe the fault is in robots.txt?

Comment: Check the robots.txt file and see if there is something like `content="nofollow"` in the page source

Comment: I could not find any robots.txt in the current setup....also I am not using any wordpress plugin like that. There was one in the joomla folder, but it has been removed from the website since I did the clean up

Comment: Without a link to your site it will be hard to know. You have checked http://example.com/robots.txt and http://example.com/portal/robots.txt?

Comment: @Howlin thanks...please update 1 for the link of the website....I just checked again....there is no robots.txt in any folder or sub-folder. Note: sub-folder "portal" no long exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've listed some topics relevant to your question:

**robots.txt**

This file instructs the search engine crawler what folders or files it should not index. So make sure your subfolders are not listed here. More information on: http://www.robotstxt.org/

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /~joe/
```

**nofollow & noindex**

NoFollow attributes can be listed in the page header or on the links themselves. It tells the search engine crawler that certain links or whole pages should not be indexes.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
</head>
```

More info: http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html

```
<a href="signin.php" rel="nofollow">sign in</a>
```

More info: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en

**Sitemaps**

[Sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en) are files containing location links to all your pages, making it easier for the search engines to index them. Consider submitting a sitemap in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

**Content:**

Google has some great [guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4598733?hl=en&ref_topic=6001981) for content and webmasters, make sure you are as compliant as you can be to maximise your search visibility.